# How to skip the expression in the beginning and ending of the string using Linux commands

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, format

`sh GetPrivateKey appname` returns below output

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- JDkldlkdlkdldldlk1G/XhgJk4TXeQ06OIunFDUVfWcvCZ+X-dkjdkjdjkdjkdjk B4SFZdjSo+fU2122jkslOreX7QYl8P3tL3BYg6dkHGkj9tbi83XrpbbRu2f0QOX3 PoiCOsV0BOiqXEUGLEQ6pWwNv9ZJCGvT/UFfmIl1SdlIMdkFDBGNhVyGz74ZS/ph OsDAwRr6yVA0V63L7ze0C31E1S1axXmD5zFnWltgNNGgTocVoEy0DeW46YNc/hms R2LeH3qpbnoMs/ZgxEYITPh3V+NQkLB5buVvQflNnYm4bOrWUy98t+hIV3mnM+wV CqW5L9dvI8qYx/fU65PdEJmIadAvP8pj4UtrwwIDAQABAoIBADQ53ubdX/iCe1Ji j4IMGbXnzLDagIiLVd7ekzyAWaJu5YjZhfoSqXlbVevGTvlpB907dPpwB28/9r6R sz3nMSkQhLB017uYrixnd17USQ9dCMPFUg61ZCIsTJkt+3SkZnsoPapGgztnNVOM jsdklsdklsdklsdklsdklsdklsdklsdFUg61ZCIsTJkt+3SkZnsoPapGgztnNVOM NuFxSBXKOecYV2I5sfo9owjOEQFt2O/1D2KCvMETgF9Fqi99321Fqe9aKHLM2NCR NuFxSBXKOecYV2I5sfo9owjOEQFt2O/1D2KCvMETgF9Fqi99321Fqe9aKHLM2NCR NuFxSBXKOecYV2I5sfo9owjOEQFt2O/1D2KCvMETgF9Fqi99321Fqe9aKHLM2NCR ywU7RqGelopd736SE4C2eFqLAhpiC+oxl7FmEIm1llITK5tlW8CK1F7MStK/akA/ JDsk1mKlsKCtDEU5c7TY2JDaTLA1qnoLFUPeiHMuCwoWBSVK9Irp3xsCgYEA4gca M3zbki6ToJ/hDNoNC5RrZI4o3KJDG9x97d8hYk0h3hhJCjFXr9MSm8Xwtp5SnAxS /bNHPSL1Wi+ZOIP4nNUG5Kto0KovPFf3U0c+LpH5kNGest9jnr49K+i5JDIItQQY NuFxSBXKOecYV2I5sfo9owjOEQFt2O/1D2KCvMETgF9Fqi99321Fqe9aKHLM2NCR BJWcRmSBKOjuqk+LRLmOEBcAn9yqCZ6tXIMUyj/LEi4ArpHHr47h9bUs5AMoD/Zo cDFIozreSs41SwTh9VO9vHvnOzbTCD3uRKrsTikjyz7D+0gZtK/wa4dcEFIhHBKC NuFxSBXKOecYV2I5sfo9owjOEQFt2O/1D2KCvMETgF9Fqi99321Fqe9aKHLM2NCR ZC7XIQ+yNaz6rkewVNP1pGfbRDWhtYDaRhoNws10leOyoqPL5Iea1fHjTSxQYROn NuFxSBXKOecYV2I5sfo9owjOEQFt2O/1D2KCvMETgF9Fqi99321Fqe9aKHLM2NCR /RxlD3ECgYAFthRafjyETgE4o8RmAraYEqK9eYLnDG/pB9zsaq+Mlh8BExU7OWqx NuFxSBXKOecYV2I5sfo9owjOEQFt2O/1D2KCvMETgF9Fqi99321Fqe9aKHLM2NCR VP9s6+olQVf7ZJyVlr9HydMBd/xdKhzXFH15AfTgIhKKzHe/OcBJTA== -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I want to format it as a private key. So I have written below command which finds the space ( " " ) in above output and displays line by line, however I don't want to split `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`  and `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`  (including the space at the end of them)

```
[user@server]$ echo `sh GetPrivateKey appname`\ | tr " " "\n"
-----BEGIN
RSA
PRIVATE
KEY-----
JDkldlkdlkdldldlk1G/XhgJk4TXeQ06OIunFDUVfWcvCZ+X-dkjdkjdjkdjkdjk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-----END
RSA
PRIVATE
KEY-----
```

I think my requirement  satisfies  with `sed` commands however I am pretty much new in Linux commands. Your help will be appreciated.

Expected output :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
JDkldlkdlkdldldlk1G/XhgJk4TXeQ06OIunFDUVfWcvCZ+X-dkjdkjdjkdjkdjk
B4SFZdjSo+fU2122jkslOreX7QYl8P3tL3BYg6dkHGkj9tbi83XrpbbRu2f0QOX3
PoiCOsV0BOiqXEUGLEQ6pWwNv9ZJCGvT/UFfmIl1SdlIMdkFDBGNhVyGz74ZS/ph
OsDAwRr6yVA0V63L7ze0C31E1S1axXmD5zFnWltgNNGgTocVoEy0DeW46YNc/hms
R2LeH3qpbnoMs/ZgxEYITPh3V+NQkLB5buVvQflNnYm4bOrWUy98t+hIV3mnM+wV
CqW5L9dvI8qYx/fU65PdEJmIadAvP8pj4UtrwwIDAQABAoIBADQ53ubdX/iCe1Ji
j4IMGbXnzLDagIiLVd7ekzyAWaJu5YjZhfoSqXlbVevGTvlpB907dPpwB28/9r6R
sz3nMSkQhLB017uYrixnd17USQ9dCMPFUg61ZCIsTJkt+3SkZnsoPapGgztnNVOM
jsdklsdklsdklsdklsdklsdklsdklsdFUg61ZCIsTJkt+3SkZnsoPapGgztnNVOM
NuFxSBXKOecYV2I5sfo9owjOEQFt2O/1D2KCvMETgF9Fqi99321Fqe9aKHLM2NCR
NuFxSBXKOecYV2I5sfo9owjOEQFt2O/1D2KCvMETgF9Fqi99321Fqe9aKHLM2NCR
NuFxSBXKOecYV2I5sfo9owjOEQFt2O/1D2KCvMETgF9Fqi99321Fqe9aKHLM2NCR
ywU7RqGelopd736SE4C2eFqLAhpiC+oxl7FmEIm1llITK5tlW8CK1F7MStK/akA/
JDsk1mKlsKCtDEU5c7TY2JDaTLA1qnoLFUPeiHMuCwoWBSVK9Irp3xsCgYEA4gca
M3zbki6ToJ/hDNoNC5RrZI4o3KJDG9x97d8hYk0h3hhJCjFXr9MSm8Xwtp5SnAxS
/bNHPSL1Wi+ZOIP4nNUG5Kto0KovPFf3U0c+LpH5kNGest9jnr49K+i5JDIItQQY
NuFxSBXKOecYV2I5sfo9owjOEQFt2O/1D2KCvMETgF9Fqi99321Fqe9aKHLM2NCR
BJWcRmSBKOjuqk+LRLmOEBcAn9yqCZ6tXIMUyj/LEi4ArpHHr47h9bUs5AMoD/Zo
cDFIozreSs41SwTh9VO9vHvnOzbTCD3uRKrsTikjyz7D+0gZtK/wa4dcEFIhHBKC
NuFxSBXKOecYV2I5sfo9owjOEQFt2O/1D2KCvMETgF9Fqi99321Fqe9aKHLM2NCR
ZC7XIQ+yNaz6rkewVNP1pGfbRDWhtYDaRhoNws10leOyoqPL5Iea1fHjTSxQYROn
NuFxSBXKOecYV2I5sfo9owjOEQFt2O/1D2KCvMETgF9Fqi99321Fqe9aKHLM2NCR
/RxlD3ECgYAFthRafjyETgE4o8RmAraYEqK9eYLnDG/pB9zsaq+Mlh8BExU7OWqx
NuFxSBXKOecYV2I5sfo9owjOEQFt2O/1D2KCvMETgF9Fqi99321Fqe9aKHLM2NCR
VP9s6+olQVf7ZJyVlr9HydMBd/xdKhzXFH15AfTgIhKKzHe/OcBJTA==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in your question. Could you please post expected sample output for better understanding of question.

Comment: I bet `sh GetPrivateKey appname`  doesn't return what you say it does and instead it returns exactly what you want but you're using an unquoted `echo` to print it and that's converting all of the newlines to blanks. That's certainly what the ```echo `sh GetPrivateKey appname``` in your question would do. Try **just** running `sh GetPrivateKey appname` instead of adding an `echo` at the front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following, written in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/KEY-+.*-+END/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  num=split(val,arr," ")
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) arr[1]
  for(i=2;i<num;i++){
     print arr[i]
  }
  print arr[num] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                        ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/KEY-+.*-+END/){                    ##Using match function to match regex KEY-+.*-+END in current line.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)              ##Creating val which has sub string of matched regex.
  num=split(val,arr," ")                     ##Splitting val into array arr.
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) arr[1]         ##printing sub string before matched regex character and printing array 1st element.
  for(i=2;i<num;i++){                        ##Going through all elements of arr here.
     print arr[i]                            ##Printing arr element with index i here.
  }
  print arr[num] substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)   ##Printing rest of line after matched regex.
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this `gnu awk`:

```sh
awk -v RS='-{5}(BEGIN|END) [^-]* KEY-{5}' '{
gsub(/ /, "\n"); ORS=RT} 1' file.rsa
```

Or using `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/-{5}(BEGIN|END) [^-]* KEY-{5}(*SKIP)(*F)|\h/\n/g' file.rsa
```

**Output:**

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
JDkldlkdlkdldldlk1G/XhgJk4TXeQ06OIunFDUVfWcvCZ+X-dkjdkjdjkdjkdjk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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Could you explain the use of `\h`, as a single `space` works as well ?

Comment: \h matches a space or a tab

Comment: I know \h matches a space or a tab, but you could(should?) have used `space` as you did for awk version.

Comment: Yes of course we could use a space instead of `\h`

Answer (score 0):

With any awk:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\n' '{
    beg = end = $0
    sub(/- .*/,"-",beg)
    sub(/.* -/,"-",end)
    gsub(/^.*- | -.*$/,"")
    $1 = $1
    print beg, $0, end
}' file
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
JDkldlkdlkdldldlk1G/XhgJk4TXeQ06OIunFDUVfWcvCZ+X-dkjdkjdjkdjkdjk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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```